# Error C# Database Update Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

i was programming an update statement on c# and SQL Database, for my grad project, i had everything going pretty fine and smooth until i faced a weird problem, once i finished my update statement, and was setting an if condition to catch the error, the msg string is giving me weird error

> use of unassigned local variable

however here's the code below.

```
string msg;
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to update book info?", "Updating", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    n.RunDml("Update into Book Values (" + txtID.Text + ",'" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtCond.Text + "','" + txtQuant.Text + "','" + txtSect.Text + "')");
    if (msg == "ok")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Updating successfully done! ", "Updating");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}
```

any help? thanks.

Comment: You're using an unassigned local variable. Stop doing so. (The use is with `if (msg == "ok")`, because you never assign a value to `msg`. It's unitialized when you use it in the above if statement. You can't do that; you can't ever use uninitialized variables.) Where do you expect the magic to happen between `string msg;` and `if (msg ==` that would somehow make it equal to `"ok"`? (Your update statement is incorrect, too. That syntax is invalid. Google *c sharp parameterized queries*.)

Comment: what IDE are you using? It should show you exactly what and where.

Comment: i used it on Insert statement and it goes okay, what is the difference, i still a beginner after all..
@KenWhite

Comment: @Usman
i have seen this topic before, didn't help me that much..

Comment: @Crowcoder
sorry, IDE?

Comment: what is the use of string msg?

Comment: and can you show code of n.RunDml

Comment: Integrated Development Environment. For instance, Visual Studio would red squiggly underline `msg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No where in your code are you setting a value for `msg` so you can't do a check to see if its equal to `"ok"`, that is what the error is stating.

Maybe you meant to do this?

```
msg = n.RunDml("Update into Book Values (" + txtID.Text + ",'" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtCond.Text + "','" + txtQuant.Text + "','" + txtSect.Text + "')");
```

But that depends on when you expect to assign a value to `msg`

Comment: the point i wanna make, is to show up to me whatever error will happen, i used it in insert statement, and it goes pretty ok without any errors, i just wondering ..

Comment: @M.Morgan - that comment made no sense... Read my answer and everyone's comments above again. The problem is `msg`, you declare it but never assign a value and until you do assign a value any comparison of that instance will raise an error.

Comment: Oh! am really sorry! i just noticed now! my bad! am very sorry!, thanks for your notice, really appreciated as well! :)